# Why is this else: pass needed for processing to continue?

Tags: python, python-2.7, if-statement, continue

Can someone explain why the `else: pass` shown below is needed in order for the rest of the code (the final `print 'processing...` statement) to be executed? Note the `print` in the `else` was put there just so I could tell that execution was indeed taking that path.

It seems like that should happen whenever the `continue` isn't executed since code in the `else` does nothing. However, if I leave the `else` out, nothing further in the `for` loop appears to be executed when the condition is False -- when files with the extension *do* exist in the directory -- which doesn't make sense to me. The docs say `continue` "continues with the next cycle of the nearest enclosing loop", fine, but if one is not executed, shouldn't processing proceed to the next statement?

```
import os

source_dir = r'C:\Downloads'
ext = '.mp3'

for dirName, subdirList, fileList in os.walk(source_dir):
    if not any(os.path.splitext(fileName)[1].lower() == ext for fileName in fileList):
        print '  skipping "{}"'.format(dirName)
        continue
    else:  # why is this clause needed to continue this iteration of a loop?
        print 'contains   "{}"'.format(dirName)
        pass

    print 'processing "{}" which has "{}" files'.format(dirName, ext)
```

**Mystery Solved**

The seemingly strange behavior was due to an indentation problem which is not visible in the code above nor normally in my text editor. It turned out that the last `print` statement was indented by 3 spaces then a tab, which makes it appear to align with the `else`, but in fact it either follows the `pass` in the `else` if it's there, or follows the `continue` in the first part of the `if`. Obviously confusing me a great deal.

Here's a screenshot of the code in my text editor with its "show space/tabs" option turned on. The red dots represent spaces and the red right guillemet (`»`) represents a tab character:

[image: screenshot of file in my editor showing bad indentation]

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's not necessary.  I changed `.mp3` to `.txt` and searched a different path, but otherwise I ran you code.  It worked as expected in both cases ...

Comment: What's the code that doesn't work? (Also, did you check that indentation is consistent, especially in the use of spaces/tabs? Seems like a prime canidate for this kind of error, as `else` can also be attached to `for`.)

Comment: I ran your code and it behave as expected, in both cases.

Comment: You never need `pass` if there's another statement in that block (in this case `print`.)

Comment: @delnan: Yes, I'm sure the indentation is correct. The problem is if I comment out the `else:` and the two line following it, the `print 'processing...` never happens. However, with `else:` in, the `print 'contains...` executes followed every time by the `print 'processing...` -- so the `else:` appears to be required for the latter to happen.

Comment: Yes, the code shown executes correctly. But if the `else:` clause is removed, the `print 'process...` statement is not executed when the should be.

Comment: @martineau -- works for me.  If it doesn't for you, then I'd say somehow you've managed to mess up your interpreter ;-)

Comment: @delnan: Ahhh, you were right, the indentation wasn't correct after all. The line with final `print` was indented with 3 spaces and a tab which in my text editor makes it line up with `else` rather than the `pass` -- but more importantly, with the `else` clause commented-out, it becomes part of clause above it and follows the `continue`, so, of course, never get executed in that case. Thanks, if you want to add a short formal answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: @martineau Thank you to have dispelled the mystery haze

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm going to answer my own question and eventually accept it. The seemingly odd behavior described was caused by an subtle indention problem, the possibility of which was first brought to my attention by user @delnan. Because it was invisible, initially I didn't think it could be the case, but eventually found it after more investigation. The details of which have been added to the end of my question.

Answer (score 6):

You don't need it.  I ran the following 2 scripts:

```
#test1.py
import os

source_dir = '.'
ext = '.txt'

for dirName, subdirList, fileList in os.walk(source_dir):
    if not any(os.path.splitext(fileName)[1].lower() == ext for fileName in fileList):
        print '  skipping "{}"'.format(dirName)
        continue
    else:  # why is this clause needed to continue this iteration of a loop?
        print 'contains   "{}"'.format(dirName)
        pass

    print 'processing "{}" which has "{}" files'.format(dirName, ext)
```

and

```
#test2.py
import os

source_dir = '.'
ext = '.txt'

for dirName, subdirList, fileList in os.walk(source_dir):
    if not any(os.path.splitext(fileName)[1].lower() == ext for fileName in fileList):
        print '  skipping "{}"'.format(dirName)
        continue
    #else:  # why is this clause needed to continue this iteration of a loop?
    #    print 'contains   "{}"'.format(dirName)
    #    pass

    print 'processing "{}" which has "{}" files'.format(dirName, ext)
```

I ran them as:

```
python test1.py > junk.log
python test2.py > junk.log2
```

Here's the first couple lines of `junk.log`:

```
test $ head junk.log
processing "." which has ".txt" files
  skipping "./new"
  skipping "./unum"
processing "./unum/kiv-unum-409befe069ac" which has ".txt" files
  skipping "./unum/kiv-unum-409befe069ac/build"
  skipping "./unum/kiv-unum-409befe069ac/build/bdist.macosx-10.3-fat"
  skipping "./unum/kiv-unum-409befe069ac/build/lib"
  skipping "./unum/kiv-unum-409befe069ac/build/lib/tests"
  skipping "./unum/kiv-unum-409befe069ac/build/lib/unum"
  skipping "./unum/kiv-unum-409befe069ac/build/lib/unum/units
```

Notice the presence of "processing" lines.

Then I `diff` the output:

```
diff junk.log junk.log2
```

with the following results:

```
0a1
> contains   "."
3a5
> contains   "./unum/kiv-unum-409befe069ac"
14a17
> contains   "./unum/kiv-unum-409befe069ac/docs"
16a20
> contains   "./unum/kiv-unum-409befe069ac/nose-1.2.1-py2.7.egg/EGG-INFO"
19a24
> contains   "./unum/kiv-unum-409befe069ac/nose-1.2.1-py2.7.egg/nose"
30a36
> contains   "./unum/kiv-unum-409befe069ac/Unum.egg-info"
```

Note that there are no differences on the "processing" lines.

Comment: You're correct, it doesn't seem like it should be needed, which was why I asked the question. Turns out it was an invisible indentation problem, see the update I added to my question. Thanks though for confirming things -- until the problem was found I was really questioning my own understanding of how `continue` works.

Comment: @martineau -- Agrv!  And I was contemplating suggesting that you try to run it with `python -t` (or `python -tt`)...

Comment: Good suggestion...which I'll try to remember to make use of before I make a fool out of myself again asking a question about something resulting from a noob mistake. It really was kind of a perfect storm in the sense that the faulty indentation in this case was caused by a tab in a place that was invisible plus changed the logic rather than causing one of the more obvious errors that sort of thing usually causes.