# Don't understand this IndentationError

Tags: python

I have written following code:

```
b=[]
c=['I am so excited about Data-X. It is important to be able to work with data.']
b=c[0].split()
count=0
for i1 in range (0, len(b)):
    for i2 in range (0, len(b[i1])): 
       if(b[i1][i2]=='e'):
            ++count
        ++i2
    ++i1
print(count)
```

This yields the following error code:

```
   File "<tokenize>", line 7
     i2=i2+1
     ^ IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level
```

I use Jupyter Notebook as editor.

Comment: This error means that a line of code is not correctly indented. The lines below that also seem to have a strange indentation. In Python, it is required by syntax for each block of code to conform to a certain indentation level. Usually, if you use spaces instead of tabs for indents, you need to keep that consistent across the board and vice versa.

Comment: @pythonlearner, you need to read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1485841/behaviour-of-increment-and-decrement-operators-in-python

Comment: @kaya3: they are not invalid but they don't do anything. Anyway, OP chose to not show the original code here (there is no such line, be it 7 or otherwise).

Answer (score 2):

The `i2=i2+1` line corresponds to your `++i2` it seems to be indented one space too many. I copied your code and received the same error you have. But when I moved the i2++ line to be directly under the `if(b..` line, I got an output of `0`

It should be noted that sometimes 'invisible' indentation errors can arise when tabs and spaces are mixed in the code (see @martineau's comment)

Comment: I think it's important to note that sometimes you can get indentation errors because you've used a mixture of tabs and spaces in the source code, so even when thing seem to "line up" the interpreter will think differently. I speak from [experience](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14900821/why-is-this-else-pass-needed-for-processing-to-continue) with the issue.

Comment: @martineau - Point taken